# lightning:inputField doesn't update for Boolean values

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have got this lightning:inputField in my component.

```
<lightning:inputField aura:id="isPrimary" fieldName="SBQQ__Primary__c" value="{!v.quoteRecord.SBQQ__Primary__c}" onchange="{!c.handleCheck}"/>
```

With a boolean value, it never gets updated on the onchange event.

I tried to debug into it. But component.find("isPrimary").get("v.value") always return the default value. component.find("isPrimary").get("v.checked") returns undefined. I have also tried changing value into checked which doesn't work as well.

Any walkaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the value...

```
<lightning:inputField aura:id="isPrimary" fieldName="SBQQ__Primary__c" onchange="{!c.handleCheck}"/>
```

And in your Javascript ...

```
handleCheck: function (component, event) {
    let quoteRecord = component.get('v.quoteRecord');
    quoteRecord.SBQQ__Primary__c = component.find("isPrimary").get("v.value");
    component.set('v.quoteRecord', quoteRecord);
}
```